# How to give a two sided (top and bottom of the page) border in selected pages in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, border

I am making an article document and want to give two sided border in some pages ( top and bottom of the pages). `\hrule` doesn't work in the `\chapter` pages. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.Se! Which border are you looking for? Please provide the Minimal Working Example (MWE)?

Comment: As the `article` class does not provide the `\chapter` macro there are no `\chapter` pages. Perhaps you should look at the reported errors for your document before coming here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt this solution to suit your needs:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2.0mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2.0mm}

\begin{document}

% Bordered pages start here
\chapter{This Chapter with Top and Bottom Borders}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Bordered Pages}

\lipsum[1-10]

\clearpage

% Un-bordered pages start here

\pagestyle{plain}
\section{Un-Bordered Pages}

\lipsum[11-20]

\clearpage

% Bordered pages start here
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section{Bordered Pages Again}
\lipsum[21-30]

\end{document}
```

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: But my page numbers are gone now.

Comment: @VivekSharma That is because you did not tell us where you whether and where you want the page numbers. See the updated solution. And I will stress on the point, *adapt*. Please see the documentation of [fancyhdr](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for the tweaking options.